# Take value from columns D and H To LastCol

Tags: vba

This is what I got:

For j = 4 & 8 To LastCol

What I need is the expression for: Variable j schould be the whole column 4 and 8 to the last column.

How to write that.

Here is my complete code:

```
Sub Neu()

   Dim FilePath As String
   Dim CellData As String
   Dim LastCol As Long
   Dim LastRow As Long
   Dim i As Long
   Dim j As Long

   LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
   LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

  CellData = ""
  FilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Excel Data (Print).txt"
  Open FilePath For Output As #2

  For i = 1 To LastRow
     For j = 4 & 8 To LastCol
        If j = LastCol Then
            CellData = CellData + Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value)
        Else
            CellData = CellData + Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value) + " "
        End If
    Next j

    Print #2, CellData
    CellData = ""
 Next i

If j = LastCol Then

    CellData = CellData + Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value)

Else

    CellData = CellData + Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value) + " "

End If

Print #2, CellData
CellData = ""

Close #2
MsgBox ("Textfile erzeugt und im selben Ordner wie Excel-Original abgelegt. Name: Excel Data (Print).txt")

End Sub
```

Comment: `For j = 4 & 8 To LastCol` this is not correct VB syntax. Please try to correct your code or post a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example.

Answer (score 0):

To do the same thing in every column, just remove the "& 8"

For j = 4 To LastCol